# Convert recursive MySQL query to PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I want to convert a working MySQL query to PostgreSQL.
I'm a newbee for PostgreSQL

Working MySQL query:

```
select  id,
        user_name,
        reported_to 
from    (select * from user_master
         order by reported_to) orrdered,
        (select @pv := 'prathap Achuthan') initialisation
where   find_in_set(reported_to, @pv)
and     length(@pv := concat(@pv, ',', user_name))
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bb94707/2

Comment: I am surprised that this even works in MySQL. First of all tables (including subquery results) are supposed to be unordered, so your `ORDER BY` clause is allowed to be neglected by the DBMS. And then you order by the name in `reported_to`. Won't this only work when the reporting person's name happens to come after the reported-to person's name in the alphabet? So, even in MySQL you should convert this into a proper standard-compliant recursive query (available as of MySQL 8).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PostgreSQL you can use a recursive CTE to implement this query:

```
WITH RECURSIVE CTE AS (
  SELECT id, user_name, reported_to
  FROM user_master
  WHERE reported_to = 'prathap Achuthan'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT um.*
  FROM user_master um
  JOIN CTE c ON c.user_name = um.reported_to
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
```

Output:

```
id  user_name               reported_to
7   Sriram Gopalakrishnan   prathap Achuthan
15  Shalini Jagdish         Sriram Gopalakrishnan
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/bb947/5)

Comment: is it possible to include prathap Achuthan in user_name

Comment: @user3386779 is this what you want? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/bb947/8